# Change parameter kCIInputSharpnessKey

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-graphics, ciimage

Why does the application drop when I change the kCIInputSharpnessKey?

```
var filters: [String : Float] = [
    kCIInputSharpnessKey : 0.4
]

let filter: CIFilter

init(image: UIImage) {
    self.image = image

    filter = CIFilter.init(name: "CIColorControls")!
}

func sharpness(n: Float) {
    filters[kCIInputSharpnessKey] = n
}

func getImage() -> CIImage? {
    let coreImage = CIImage(image: image)

    filter.setValue(coreImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)

    for (key, value) in filters {
        filter.setValue(value, forKey: key)
    }

    return filter.outputImage
}
```

Error message:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key inputSharpness.'

Comment: What type is `filter`?

Comment: It is CIFilter.

Comment: Not all filters have a `kCIInputSharpnessKey` input parameter.

Comment: Have you checked the [reference of `CIColorControls`](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIColorControls)? It does not have a parameter named `inputSharpness` (=`kCIInputSharpnessKey `).